# O que o operador "OU" faz num Enum?

Tags: c#, enums

O que o operador lógico `|` (ou) faz nesse Enum?

```
public enum Status
{
    Running = 1,
    Inactive = 2,
    Error = Inactive | Running
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Este não é o operador lógico "ou" (que é representado por `||`). Este é o [operador de "bitwise or"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxszd0kx.aspx) ("ou em todos os bits"), e ele realiza esta operação nos números.

```
1 = 0000 0001 (binário)
2 = 0000 0010 (binário)
1 | 2 = 0000 0011 (binário) = 3
```

Então a declaração acima define o campo `Error` com um valor `3`.

Isso é mais usado em enums declarado com o atributo `[Flags]`, e nesse caso não parece muito indicado (já que se o status é um `Error` isso provavelmente quer dizer que o status não será `Running`). A utilização de flags enum é recomendada quando você tem opções não mutuamente exclusivas. Por exemplo, veja a declaração abaixo:

```
[Flags]
public enum TextAttributes
{
    None = 0,
    Bold = 1,
    Italic = 2,
    Underline = 4,
    BoldAndItalic = Bold | Italic,
    BoldAndUnderline = Bold | Underline,
    ItalicAndUnderline = Italic | Underline,
    All = Bold | Italic | Underline
}
```

Comment: Gostaria de adicionar: para verificar se uma instancia do `enum` contem uma flag em particular, usa-se o *bitwise and* (`if((textAttribute & TextAttributes.Bold) == TextAttributes.Bold)`) ou o metodo [`HasFlag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag(v=vs.110).aspx) (`if(textAttribute.HasFlag(TextAttributes.Bold))`).